# Twitter for blackberry

Tags: twitter, blackberry

I want to integrate twitter api in my BB (OS 5 and above) application. Is there any api available. I already tried twitter api me, but no success.

Please halp.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the Twitter APIME SDK to work well.

For my particular purposes, I have updated it a little and provided a simplified interface that you can find here:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Twitter-integration-exception/m-p/2520587#M221951

Hopefully this link takes you to the post that contains the download for my updated project, if not search the Thread for it.

All I wanted to do is provide an interface that sends a tweet and posts to a facebook wall, and the supplied code does that fine for me in OS 5.0 and above.

Comment: i had tried that Twitter API as well as third party lib but it is useless. not working for OS 5 and 6.

Comment: Hi Peter Strange. Your answer is very help full to me. I have downloaded this library and other demo projects and run it (Specially for twitter only). I am able to tweet successfully but only using account in which i have created my application. If i try to tweet using different account then, it is showing alert like "Tweeted" but nothing is shown on twitter site. Can you please help me on this ?

Comment: Resolved, i was cheching in wrong account. Thank you so much for your help. I have one another question, is there any api/demo application for BB to post photo on twitter. Can u please suggest.